# How to get data from url that is in response JSON - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, get

I am using GET to `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/` in JSON. That JSON contains an array of links of `episode`, like `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/4`. How can I GET episode name like `S01E04` from `episode` link?
My code now is:

character.class

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:rick_and_morty_characters/services/webservice.dart';
import 'package:rick_and_morty_characters/utils/constants.dart';

class Character {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String status;
  final String image;
  final Episode episode;
  Character({this.id, this.name, this.status, this.image, this.episode});
  factory Character.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    return Character(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      status: json['status'],
      image: json['image'] ?? Constants.DEFAULT_AVATAR,
      episode: Episode.fromJson(json['episode'])
    );
  }

  static Resource<List<Character>> get all {
    return Resource(
        url: Constants.R_A_M_CHARACTERS,
        parse: (response) {
          final result = json.decode(response.body);
          Iterable list = result['results'];
          return list.map((model) => Character.fromJson(model)).toList();
        }
    );
  }
}

class Episode {
  final String episodeLink;
  Episode({this.episodeLink});
  factory Episode.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    return Episode(
      episodeLink: json['episode']
    );
  }
}
```

constants.dart

```
class Constants {
  static final String R_A_M_CHARACTERS = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/';
  static final String DEFAULT_AVATAR = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg';
}
```

webservice.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class Resource<T> {
  final String url;
  T Function(Response response) parse;
  Resource({this.url,this.parse});
}

class Webservice {
  Future<T> load<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    final response = await http.get(resource.url);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pasting an example of your JSON here

```
  https://app.quicktype.io/
```

the build an object and copy paste the dart code.

Then, when you get a response from your api, just parse your JSON to the newly created object.

And the just use the object as you wish to get the info.